# server response sets boolean true/false

Tags: java, sockets, if-statement, io, boolean

I am working with a program right now which sends/receives messages to/from server.

I have protected void called onNotice in ClassOne which gets parameters from the server when server issues a "notice" (aka message):

```
onNotice(sourceNick, notice){}
```

I have a method in ClassTwo which triggers the server response for onNotice:

```
noticeCheck(sender){
sendNotice("receiver", "sendNotice triggers server response" + sender);
}

//followed by next action
nextAction(){
if(noticeTrue){
doSomething;
return;
}
doSomethingElse;
}
```

How can I create noticeTrue in ClassOne for nextAction? Shouldn't nextAction have to wait for onNotice to receive server response before deciding if noticeTrue is true or false?

Thanks a lot for any assistance

Comment: I added a static boolean at the top of the class leading noticeTrue to false. then changed noticeTrue to true when onNoticed did it's thang. Thanks @Matteo !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assign false value at noticeTrue and change value to true when onNotice

Comment: giving it a shot now